# Could someone explain in-depth how to change a bufferedimage to a bytebuffer?

Tags: java, opengl, bufferedimage, lwjgl, bytebuffer

For OpenGL. There are many texture loaders that I could use, but what are the basics for what you need changing a bufferedimage to bytebuffer? I just don't want to copy/paste the code directly, I'd rather know what it means.

For starters, what information does the bytebuffer need to get from bufferedimage and how is it gotten?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, just updating that I discussed with some people on a forum and they explained to me the answer. So if anyone in the future has the same question and this is one of their Google search results,
[here](http://www.java-gaming.org/topics/in-depth-explanation-of-bufferedimage-to-bytebuffer/25866/view.html) is the thread where the answer was found.